# uploading a background image

Tags: html, database, image

I have used an image as a background in my website and it seems to be working fine, but the inspect element on chrome keeps giving me a 404 message (not found). I'm not sure why. It seems to fail to be linked to the database.

here is my code:

```
   <img src="/images/uploads/background.jpg" alt="pattern" name="fsbg" width="2983" height="1551" id="fsbg" />
```

Comment: Provide the 404 error, sounds unrelated.

Comment: Are you running this on any CMS platform? These kind of anomalies can happen when the .htaccess file isn't setup properly.

Comment: Yes, i'm using expressionengine

Comment: Could you please provide the exact 404 error and the contents of your .htaccess file?

Comment: <FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Use PHP5.4 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php

Comment: and as for the content of the 404, can you tell me what you mean by the full content of it?

Comment: it says: Get http://{my site url}/images/background.jpg   404 (not found)  index.php:616